# Is there a SQL statement that can return the appropriate number of responses through a HABTM association based on an input parameter?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, sqlite

I've been trying to return a response to an API endpoint I created, and the response works fine but my issue has been returning the appropriate number of elements from an object called mobile.

```rb
Request:
{
    "team_id": 4,
    "title": "Test message",
    "content": "This is a test message."
}

Response:
{
    "res": {
        "team_id": 4,
        "sms": {
            "id": "cd0a6e09-22de-46e2-a114-3a7cb2f29add",
            "mobile": [],
            "content": "This is a test message.",
            "sent_at": "2021-09-30T17:51:30.513+05:30"
        }
    }
}
```

I have three models: `team`, `message` and `developer`. `team` and `message` have a has many and belongs to (team has many messages and message belongs to team) association, while `team` and `developer` have a many-to-many association.

Mobile shouldn't be empty, it should be an array that is filled with string elements that have number characters in them according to the number of `dev_ids` under one team. The `team_id`, in its name, only exists in `message` but still should be acting as a foreign key between it and `team`. Honestly, kinda confused here as to how I should be approaching the joins and stuff.

Eg of team:

```rb
team
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pod-B",
        "dept_name": "Research",
        "created_at": "2021-09-20T16:48:49.306Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-23T06:01:00.722Z",
        "dev_ids": "[2, 4, 6]"
    }
```

Eg of developer:

```rb
developer 
   {
        "id": 2,
        "full_name": "Aroosa Ahmed",
        "email": "arrosa@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5593270301",
        "created_at": "2021-09-23T07:30:02.202Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-23T07:30:02.202Z"
    }
```

I have tried a couple variations on how to approach the mobile issue but none of them are netting the appropriate responses as you can see from my controller.

```rb
trigger_controller

require 'securerandom'
class TriggerController < ApplicationController
    def notification
        @message = Message.new(message_params)
        @id = params[:team_id]
        @content = params[:content]
        @mob = Team.joins(:developers).where(id: @id).pluck(:mobile)
        #@mob = Team.joins(:developers).pluck(:mobile)
        #@mob = Team.includes(:developers).find(@id).pluck(:'developers.mobile')
        tim = Time.now

        if @message.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: { 'res' => {:team_id => @id, 'sms' => { "id" => SecureRandom.uuid, :mobile => @mob, :content => @content, "sent_at" => tim } } } }
          end
        else
            render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

    end


    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def message_params
      params.permit(:team_id, :title, :content)
    end
end
```

Here's the schema to give a better idea of the overall DB:

```rb
schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_09_30_043758) do

  create_table "developers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "mobile"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "developers_teams", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "team_id"
    t.integer "developer_id"
    t.index ["developer_id"], name: "index_developers_teams_on_developer_id"
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_developers_teams_on_team_id"
  end

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "team_id", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_messages_on_team_id"
  end

  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "dept_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "dev_ids", default: "--- []\n"
  end

  add_foreign_key "messages", "teams"
end
```

Models:

```rb
developer.rb

class Developer < ApplicationRecord
    validates :full_name, presence: true
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end


team.rb

class Team < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :messages
    serialize :dev_ids
    has_and_belongs_to_many :developers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Think we were both missing the joy of has_and_belongs_to_many, which is that is has the related table as a method. Try this...

```
def notification
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  @team_id = params[:team_id]
  @content = params[:content]
  @mob = Team.find(@team_id).developers.pluck(:mobile)
  tim = Time.now

  if @message.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: { 'res' => {:team_id => @team_id, 'sms' => { "id" => SecureRandom.uuid, :mobile => @mob, :content => @content, "sent_at" => tim } } } 
      end
    end
  else
    render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

end
```

Comment: Getting an issue where it's trying to find `developer.team_id` but that doesn't really exist. `team_id` is a foreign key on `message` that is supposed to keep track of the default `id` on `team`. But also there's the `team_id` under the join table of `developers_teams` so I'm guessing that's what you're referencing?

Comment: Yeah -- I usually use has_many through, but changed my answer to take advantage of the HBTM.  Couldn't test, so YMMV.